# GNS construction for a normal state on a von Neumann algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. For any faithful normal state $\omega$ on $M$, according to the GNS construction, we have $\omega(x)=\langle x \Omega,\Omega\rangle$, where $\Omega$ is a cyclic vector.

For any two different faithful normal states, are the cyclic vectors in the above construction the same?

Comment: Look at answers by "Martin Argerami" about GNS construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they both coincide with the unit of $M$, so in a sense they are indeed the same.  However the two GNS
representations take place in DIFFERENT Hilbert spaces,  namely the completion of $M$ relative to two different inner
products.

If the states are $\omega _1$ and $\omega _2$,  and the corresponding GNS representations are $(\pi _1,H_1,\xi _1)$ and $(\pi _2,H_2,\xi _2)$,
then both  $H_1$ and $H_2$
contain a dense copy of $M$ and, for every $m$ on $M$,  the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
  H_1 @<\iota_1<<M @>\iota_2>> H_2\\
  @V\pi_1(m)VV @VL_mVV @VV\pi_2(m)V\\
  H_1 @<\iota_1<<M @>\iota_2>> H_2\\
  \end{CD}
commutes, where $L_m$ is the operator of left-multiplication by $m$, and $\iota_1$ and $\iota_2$ are the inclusion maps.

This might give an impression that $π_1$ and $π_2$ are equivalent representations, and indeed they are (!) when
restricted to the dense subspaces $\iota_1(M)$ and $\iota_2(M)$.

However, the extra vectors added in the completion process strongly depend  on the states $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$, so the representations $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ might very well be inequivalent!